# What was the significance of the last scene in Mahanati?

Tags: plot-explanation, mahanati

In the last scene of *Mahanati*, Madhuravani comes up to Savitri Amma and hands her a paper clipping with the photo of a man called Sankarayya,  who is supposedly Savitri's father. And right after this, we cut back to a scene where a younger Savitri and her "Stone sculpture" father are shown and on base of the sculpture, the words Sankarayya were shown.

What did this signify?

- That the sculpture was actually her fathers?
- or if this lead was yet another wrong lead?
- or if this means symbolically she did come from a talented "hari-katha" saying background?
- or was it just another throwback scene to wrap up the movie?
- or something else?

I didn't actually understand this part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sankarayya is the stone sculpture. She was about to go and talk to him, probably share her pain. But unfortunately she felt sick on the next day, and madhuravani was trying to find out who was this sankarayya.

According to the director, sankarayya is a fictitious character.

Comment: Can you please provide a verified source for this ? Because I was under the impression that the statue of sankarayya was really of her fathers but she didn't know it all these years, and finally knew it on her deathbed, hence giving her closure.